# How to make spree, rails and liqpay to work together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I have a Rails application with Spree. I need to use Liqpay for payment and i have some troubles with it's API. I have inserted Liqpay button it is looks like

```
  <a href="https://www.liqpay.com/api/pay?public_key=<public_key>&private_key=<private_key>&signature=<%=@sign%>&amount=<%=@order.total%>&order_id=<%= @order.id%>currency=RUB&description=Desc&type=buy&sandbox=1&pay_way=card,delayed&server_url=<my_site_api_url>&language=ru&return_url=<return_url>">
```

signature @sign is calculated using gem Lickpay https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/liqpay

```
  request = Liqpay::Request.new (<some_params>)
  @sign = request.signature
```

this is not exectly the way, described in Liqpay docs, but that does not work too((
There is a way to make requsts to Spree without signature, but a can't cend order_id in this case, but I need it. Is there a way to calculate it correctly, or to deal without it?  How I will get to know order_id in this case? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiinally, made it. It is pretty easy and clear, what I had to is read documentation on Liqpay carefully. So, the first is on need to install this lib - https://github.com/liqpay/sdk-ruby
and then follow liqpay guides! One thing one need to note - is that signature should be calculated with exactly the same params, request to Liqpay Api is made.